# create line connecting pairs of points from file

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have a timing program which produces the rough output of

```
1024   185.6778
2048   186.65567
4096   179.345
8192   204.2300
```

(where the left is array size and the right is the time taken).

I save this to a file called test.dat.  I would want a line connecting the points to be plotted, something like is seen here (taken from a gnuplot demo [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/)):
[image]

While I can do `plot 'test.dat'` , this just plots the individual points. What command/option must I run in order that the points be connected? Additionally, I would like to have a fixed y-axis between 0 and 1000, currently it scrolls infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for connecting points is the `w l` (with lines) command, so `plot 'test.dat' w l`

Comment: I guess it is mentioned somewhere (although can't find it anymore), default plotting style for functions is `with lines` and default style for data is `with points`. The examples in the link are all functions, except the very last plot. What about the fixed y-axis? Maybe `set yrange [0:1000]`? You can accept your own answer for not letting your question appear unanswered.